# PipelineDB Continuous View Failed Assertion !(ActiveSnapshotSet())

Tags: pipelinedb

I have two continuous views: `tikets2` and `second_view`

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW tickets2 AS 
   SELECT ticketid,
     TO_TIMESTAMP(min(event_time)::double precision /1000000) as t0,
     keyed_min(event_time, status) as t0_status,
     TO_TIMESTAMP(max(event_time)::double precision /1000000) as tc,
     keyed_max(event_time, status) as tc_status
   FROM tickets_stream2 
   group by ticketid;

CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW second_view AS
SELECT (new).tc FROM output_of('tickets2’);
```

When I insert data into `tickets_stream2`, I get an assertion error.

> TRAP: FailedAssertion("!(ActiveSnapshotSet())", File: "postgres.c",
>   Line: 824, PID: 5275, Query: tickets2)

Removing `second_view`, the data insertion into `tickets_stream2` executes without problems.

I can't figure out what I am missing.

Obs. I am using PipelineDB 0.9.7

EDIT:

Meanwhile I tried without the TO_TIMESTAMP() function and no exception occurred.

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW tickets2 AS 
            SELECT 
                ticketid, 
                min(event_time) as t0, 
                keyed_min(event_time, status) as t0_status,
                max(event_time) as tc, 
                keyed_max(event_time, status) as tc_status   
            FROM tickets_stream_test_output 
            GROUP BY ticketid;
```

EDIT 2, with 0.9.7u3
(*may be useful for others*)

I tested with the updated version. I'm not getting the assertion failure anymore, but still an error occurs when I insert data into test_version_stream.

```
CREATE STREAM test_version_stream(event_time bigint, ticketid uuid, status text);

CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW test_version_view AS 
   SELECT ticketid,
     TO_TIMESTAMP(min(event_time)::double precision /1000000) as t
   FROM test_version_stream
   GROUP BY ticketid;

CREATE CONTINUOUS VIEW e_test_version_view AS
SELECT (new).t FROM output_of('test_version_view');
```

I changed the order of functions `min` and `to_timestamp` and all went fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with the latest update to the 0.9.7 release:

https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipelinedb/releases

Comment: I still get an error, but changing the order of  `min` and `to_timestamp` functions worked. Thank you for your time. Ana